# Rails 4 Controller Flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller, I have:

```
def create
  if @subtask.save
    format.html {redirect_to :action => :index, :flash => "Subtask was saved!"}
  end
end
```

But there is no flash message! How do I get a flash message to let the user know they successfully created the new subtask after being redirecting to the index page with all the subtask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to show a :notice using the flash.
The flash itself is connected to a hash and you can not just put values in there.

If you want to use the :notice key, it would be:

```
def create
  if @subtask.save
    format.html {redirect_to :action => :index, :flash => { notice: "Subject was saved!" }}
  end
end
```

You can then access the notice in your view using:

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

For details check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { @subtask.save ? redirect_to subtasks_path, notice: "Subtask was saved!" : render :new }
    end
end
```